# iphone : getting error of "_AudioSessionSetProperty" while playing recording

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, avaudioplayer, avaudiosession

i am getting error of ,

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_AudioSessionSetProperty", referenced from
```

while playing my recording.I have included,

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import <CoreAudio/CoreAudioTypes.h>
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>
```

frameworks and its header files.
what is missing?

Comment: This is on the simulator?  Yes?

Comment: on iphone also this error is occurring

Answer (score 8):

did u include the AudioToolbox framework to the application?

Comment: as describe in my question, i have included AudioToolbox framework to my app

Comment: Assuming u r using Xcode 3, Right click on Groups & Files in project navigator. Expand `Targets`. Expand Link Binary With Libraries. Check whether the framework is checked or not.

Comment: i am using xcode4 and linking you have told is done i mean it is checked as Required in target->Link binary with libraries

Comment: If it is already linked, then there would not be any problem. Try do build after clean.

Comment: no,still problem. i have to comment it out now.thanx for ur help